# Visual Studio 2010 BreakPoints not hit on one page but hit on the other

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project I inherited on only one of the pages the break points are not being hit. They are not hollow, they are solid and look as if they are going to be hit when I run the code, but when the page loads (one of the break points) it does not break. Now I added a break point to a different page (onLoad) and it does it. I have never come across this before, does anyone one have any insight on this crazy visual studio behavior?

I have tried to clean and rebuild the project and still not working.

aspx page:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Screener.aspx.cs" Inherits="Screener.Screener" %>
```

.cs page:

```
 namespace Screener
 {
       public partial class Screener : System.Web.UI.Page
```

One thing I just noticed, the code behind page is 1633 lines long, should that matter?

I just deleted the old page and re-created it and still nothing.

Comment: Have you set the Location of the breakpoint already to allow different source?

Comment: Yes still does not make a difference.

Comment: Then just to make sure that the code you want to break in it's called, throw an exception (or print a message) in the point where you want the break. If you didn't already do that.

Comment: I did a response.Write("TEST") in Page_Load and it does not show up.

Comment: you need to post the header of the aspx page and the top part of the code behind, there must be something wrong there

Comment: I just commented out a bunch of code and its clearly not hitting the code behind.

Comment: Is there another partial class named Screener.Screener?  Did you override OnLoad method or attach to the Load event?

Comment: Nope no other class and no override I think its a file length issue.

Comment: Add a label to the aspx and see if that shows up. Maybe you're not loading this page at all somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to force a breakpoint (in code)

- Add the System.Diagnostic namespace to your code behind
- add an additional line of code Debugger.Break();

This will force the debugger to break (if running) otherwise a dialog box will appear asking to debug. Should identify if this is an issue with visual studio caching something or the code that you wish to debug is not being called.

Do not forget to remove from code when done.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx